# react-native Cannot find cannot find symbol Freshchat after upgrading react-native-freshchat-sdk

Tags: react-native, freshdesk

I upgraded freshchat from `"react-native-freshchat-sdk": "^2.6.4"` to `"react-native-freshchat-sdk": "^4.0.3"` and tried running the android app but the build failed with error

```
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found for android.ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
500 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 494 up-to-date
/Users/angellanaigaga/Desktop/numida/trackapp/frontend/trackapp-native/android/app/src/main/java/com/numidatech/numida/NumidaMessagingService.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.Freshchat;
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Freshchat
  location: package com.freshchat.consumer.sdk
/Users/angellanaigaga/Desktop/numida/trackapp/frontend/trackapp-native/android/app/src/main/java/com/numidatech/numida/NumidaMessagingService.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Freshchat.isFreshchatNotification(message)) {
        ^
  symbol:   variable Freshchat
  location: class NumidaMessagingService
/Users/angellanaigaga/Desktop/numida/trackapp/frontend/trackapp-native/android/app/src/main/java/com/numidatech/numida/NumidaMessagingService.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
      Freshchat.handleFcmMessage(this.getApplicationContext(), message);
      ^
  symbol:   variable Freshchat
  location: class NumidaMessagingService
Note: /Users/angellanaigaga/Desktop/numida/trackapp/frontend/trackapp-native/android/app/src/debug/java/com/numidatech/numida/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the Freshworks [and
roid Github](https://github.com/freshworks/freshchat-android), I had to update my App Module gradle file (app/build.gradle) to include `freshdesk:freshchat` in dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:{latestVersion}'
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but adding this line alone doesn't seem to resolve it for me.
What version of gradle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
implementation (project(':react-native-freshchat-sdk')){
    exclude group: 'com.github.freshworks'
}
implementation 'com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:5.3.3'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?